# Make a task run periodically with time given by user

Tags: python, django, celery

I have to built a Django application, to send e-mail notifications to the user. But the user wants to set the time period at which their e-mail is sent. I read that celery has a periodic task functionality, but the time must be set beforehand, so how can i make a periodic task with time given by user, with celery?

```
class UserMail(models.Model):
    user_mail = models.EmailField()
    auto_send_mail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_set = models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Time set to get a time given by the user when they post in the form.

Comment: You can use celery ETA, so when the user save the time_set you can add task to celery with timedelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/InterestingLab/elasticmanager/wiki/How-to-dynamically-add---remove-periodic-tasks-to-Celery) article can help with what you need.

Another option is to instead design a periodic task running each 1 min, that will query `UserMail` to check if some records do have `time_set` within during minute and send emails.
Also note that periodic tasks scheduler in celery is not designed to handle thousands of scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Use threading.
You can get more details at https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

So Basically you want to create the Task with the time inputted by the user. What O have is an API, and I take the input from the user in the form of a POST request.

Here, I coped the data sent by the user in a variable named response.
Then, We create a schedule with the time given by the user in minutes. 
and Finally we make the required periodic task. In your case, if you have a function called send_mail in tasks.py file in your app named resources, the code will look like this.

```
response = request.data.copy()

schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
    every=response['interval'],
    period=IntervalSchedule.MINUTES,
)

task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(
    interval=schedule,
    name=f'{send mail task for user {self.request.user.id}| '
    task='urlmonitor.tasks.send_mail',
    args=json.dumps([self.request.user.email]),
    # expires=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=30)
)
```

Comment: Hi, please fix your indentation!

Comment: Hi @Adam, Thank you for notifying. I fixed the indentation.